# Camel stops taking messages off JMS queue

Tags: apache-camel, jms, osgi, apache-karaf

We are using Camel and ActiveMQ in a Karaf OSGI server.

We have a route which takes messages off a JMS queue and passes them to an HTTPS endpoint. Here's the java code that builds the route:

```
       from(fromURI).autoStartup(true)
            .onException(Throwable.class).handled(true).maximumRedeliveries(0)
                    .to("bean:our.own.OutputErrorHandler").end()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Received batch to Output for Queue: " + queue.getName())
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
            .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
            .to(outputURI)
            .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
            .routeId(queue.getName() + "-Output-HTTP")
            .end();
```

where the 'fromURI' is something like 'jms:queue:201.output', and the 'outputUri' is the HTTPS endpoint URL.

Now this works fine, but occasionally the destination HTTP endpoint never returns and doesn't disconnect, so the whole route blocks, and the JMS queue just builds and builds.

Which timeout parameter should I use on the HTTP URI to define a response timeout for the endpoint, so that it fails after a certain amount of time? Note this is for version 2.15.4 of Camel (yes, I know it's old).

Comment: Your discovery basically makes the original question here moot. You should rewrite your entire question to ask about the real problem (i.e. the infinitely blocking HTTP call). Also, keep in mind that asking for the "best" option in a given situation is essentially opinion-based since "best" is relative to the specifics of your particular use-case.

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks, I should of done what you said. Have edited now.

Comment: You can set timeout options on the camel-http component/endpoint

Comment: The documentation for camel-http is a bit misleading in this case. To configure timeouts you'll need to prefix the option with `httpClient.` example: `https://example.com/api?httpClient.socketTimeout={{http.socketTimeout}}&httpClient.connectionRequestTimeout={{http.connectionRequestTimeout}}&httpClient.connectTimeout={{http.connectTimeout}}`

Comment: @ClausIbsen are you able to tell us which timeout option should be used with the 2.15.4 version of the HTTP Component? The [2.x documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http-component.html) doesn't seem to show any.

Answer (score 0):

The [2.x documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http-component.html#_using_client_timeout_so_timeout) refers to a test named [`HttpSOTimeoutTest`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.15.4/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpSOTimeoutTest.java) and on the `2.15.4` tag it uses `httpClient.SocketTimeout`, e.g.:

```
httpClient.SocketTimeout=5000
```

It's worth noting that this test is using the **HTTP4** component and not the HTTP component.

As noted in the [HTTP4 documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html):

> Camel-http4 uses [Apache HttpClient 4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) while camel-http uses [Apache HttpClient 3.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

So it looks like you need to change components as well as adding the aforementioned parameter.

Comment: No, sorry. When we try that parameter on the endpoint URI we get a CAMEL error which says: `There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{SocketTimeout=5000}]`

Comment: Note that `httpClient.soTimeout` does not produce an error, but when we set it fairly low (say 10ms) on a test machine it doesn't time out, even though the request takes over 400ms to complete.

Comment: I updated my answer with some new info.

Comment: Did you try using the HTTP4 component?

Comment: Any feedback here?